# How to keep check box checked after button click for update

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview, datagridview

Please help me to keep checkbox is checked after checking checkbox for updating corresponding row in Gridview.this my complete source code.Please help Me to keep checkbox inside Gridview checked after update button click.I met scenario that in order to identify which user's data going to be update so.Please help me friends.

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True"   
            AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID"  onpageindexchanging=" grvDetails_PageIndexChanging">
            <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Page">
                         <HeaderTemplate>
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="checkAll" runat="server" onclick = "checkAll(this);"/>                               
                         </HeaderTemplate>
                         <ItemTemplate>                                
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="radID" runat="server"  onclick ="CheckSingleCheckbox(this)" />
                         </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" ReadOnly="True"/>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName"  HeaderText="FirstName"/>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName"/>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Gender" HeaderText="Gender"/>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email"/>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Phone" HeaderText="Phone"/>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ContactAddres" HeaderText="ContactAddres"/>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="State" HeaderText="ContactState"/>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Country" HeaderText="ContactCountry"/>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="CommunicationAddress" HeaderText="CommunicationAddress"/>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="State1" HeaderText="CommunicationState"/>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Country1" HeaderText="CommunicationCountry"/>

                    <asp:BoundField DataField="statec" HeaderText="ContactCountry" ShowHeader="false"  />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="countryc" HeaderText="CommunicationAddress" ShowHeader="false" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="CommunicationState" HeaderText="CommunicationState" ShowHeader="false"  />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="CommunicationCountry" HeaderText="CommunicationCountry" ShowHeader="false"  />

              </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>


And this is my c# page and I'm posting code for update

    using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Collections;
namespace Reg
{
    public partial class Registration : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                gridView();
                populate1();
                populate2();
            }
        }
        public void populate1()
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            SqlConnection con;
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ApplicationServices"].ToString());
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("select *from CountryDetail", con);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
            da.Fill(ds);
            ddlCountryPermanent.DataTextField = ds.Tables[0].Columns["Country"].ToString();
            ddlCountryPermanent.DataValueField = ds.Tables[0].Columns["CID"].ToString();
            ddlCountryPermanent.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            ddlCountryPermanent.DataBind();
            ddlCountryPermanent.Items.Insert(0, "Select");
            ddlCountryCommunication.DataTextField = ds.Tables[0].Columns["Country"].ToString();
            ddlCountryCommunication.DataValueField = ds.Tables[0].Columns["CID"].ToString();
            ddlCountryCommunication.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            ddlCountryCommunication.DataBind();
            ddlCountryCommunication.Items.Insert(0, "Select");
        }
        public void populate2()
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            SqlConnection con;
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ApplicationServices"].ToString());
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("select *from StatesDetail", con);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
            da.Fill(ds);
            ddlStatePermanent.DataTextField = ds.Tables[0].Columns["State"].ToString();
            ddlStatePermanent.DataValueField = ds.Tables[0].Columns["SID"].ToString();
            ddlStatePermanent.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            ddlStatePermanent.DataBind();
            ddlStatePermanent.Items.Insert(0, "Select");
            ddlStateCommunication.DataTextField = ds.Tables[0].Columns["State"].ToString();
            ddlStateCommunication.DataValueField = ds.Tables[0].Columns["SID"].ToString();
            ddlStateCommunication.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            ddlStateCommunication.DataBind();
            ddlStateCommunication.Items.Insert(0, "Select");
        }
        protected void saveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            SqlConnection con;
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ApplicationServices"].ToString());
            cmd = new SqlCommand("proc_Registers", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", txtFirstName.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", txtLastName.Text);
            if (RdoGender.SelectedItem.Value == "0")
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", "0");
            }
            else
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", "1");
            }
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtEmail.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone", txtPhone.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContactAddres", txtAddressCon.Text);
            var statcon = ddlStatePermanent.SelectedItem.Value;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContactState", statcon);
            var ddlCourtyCon = ddlCountryPermanent.SelectedItem.Value;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContactCountry", ddlCourtyCon);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CommunicationAddress", txtAddressPer.Text);
            var statper = ddlStateCommunication.SelectedItem.Value;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CommunicationState", statper);
            var ddlCourtyPer = ddlCountryCommunication.SelectedItem.Value;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CommunicationCountry", ddlCourtyPer);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            gridView();
        }
        public void gridView()
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ApplicationServices"].ToString());
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("proc_FinalDataGridviewNew", con);
            da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            da.Fill(ds);
            GridView1.DataSource = ds;
            GridView1.PageSize = 5;
            GridView1.Columns[1].Visible = true;
            GridView1.Columns[13].Visible = true;
            GridView1.Columns[14].Visible = true;
            GridView1.Columns[15].Visible = true;
            GridView1.Columns[16].Visible = true;
            Page.DataBind();
            GridView1.Columns[1].Visible = false;
            GridView1.Columns[13].Visible = false;
            GridView1.Columns[14].Visible = false;
            GridView1.Columns[15].Visible = false;
            GridView1.Columns[16].Visible = false;
        }
        protected void grvDetails_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
        {
            GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
            DataBind();
            gridView();
        }
        protected void GridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Row.Cells[13].Visible = false;
            e.Row.Cells[14].Visible = false;
            e.Row.Cells[15].Visible = false;
            e.Row.Cells[16].Visible = false;
        }
        protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
            {
                var chk = row.FindControl("radID") as CheckBox;
                if (chk.Checked)
                {
                    var ID = row.Cells[1].Text;
                    var fname = row.Cells[2].Text;
                    var lname = row.Cells[3].Text;
                    var gendr = row.Cells[4].Text;
                    var mail = row.Cells[5].Text;
                    var phne = row.Cells[6].Text;
                    var addrscon = row.Cells[7].Text;
                    var statecon = row.Cells[13].Text;
                    var countrycon = row.Cells[14].Text;
                    var addrsper = row.Cells[10].Text;
                    var stateper = row.Cells[15].Text;
                    var countryper = row.Cells[16].Text;
                    txtID.Text = ID;
                    txtFirstName.Text = fname;
                    txtLastName.Text = lname;
                    string gndr;
                    if (gendr == "Male")
                    {
                        gndr = "0";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        gndr = "1";
                    }
                    RdoGender.SelectedValue = gndr;
                    txtEmail.Text = mail;
                    txtPhone.Text = phne;
                    txtAddressCon.Text = addrscon;
                    ddlStatePermanent.SelectedValue = statecon;
                    ddlCountryPermanent.SelectedValue = countrycon;
                    txtAddressPer.Text = addrsper;
                    ddlStateCommunication.SelectedValue = stateper;
                    ddlCountryCommunication.SelectedValue = countryper;
                    DataBind();
                    gridView();
                }
                else
                {
                    lblMessage.Text = "*Please select any row to Update";
                }
            }
        }

        protected void updateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string id = txtID.Text;
            string fname = txtFirstName.Text;
            string lname = txtLastName.Text;
            string gendr = RdoGender.Text;
            string mail = txtEmail.Text;
            string phne = txtPhone.Text;
            string addrscon = txtAddressCon.Text;
            string statecon = ddlStatePermanent.SelectedItem.Value;
            string countrycon = ddlCountryPermanent.SelectedItem.Value;
            string addrsper = txtAddressCon.Text;
            string stateper = ddlStateCommunication.SelectedItem.Value;
            string countryper = ddlCountryCommunication.SelectedItem.Value;
            SqlConnection con = con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ApplicationServices"].ToString());
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("proc_UpdateRegisters", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", id);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", fname);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", lname);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", gendr);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", mail);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone", phne);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContactAddres", addrscon);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContactState", statecon);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContactCountry", countrycon);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CommunicationAddress", addrsper);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CommunicationState", stateper);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CommunicationCountry", countryper);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            con.Close();
            gridView();
        }
        // row delete
        protected void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StringCollection idCollection = new StringCollection();
            string strID = string.Empty;
            for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                CheckBox chkDelete = (CheckBox)GridView1.Rows[i].
                                 Cells[0].FindControl("radID");
                if (chkDelete != null)
                {
                    if (chkDelete.Checked)
                    {
                        strID = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text;
                        idCollection.Add(strID);
                    }
                }
            }
            if (idCollection.Count > 0)
            {
                DeleteMultipleRecords(idCollection);
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
            else
            {
                lblMessage.Text = "*Please select any row to delete";
            }
            DataBind();
            gridView();
        }
        private void DeleteMultipleRecords(StringCollection idCollection)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ApplicationServices"].ToString());
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            string IDs = "";
            foreach (string id in idCollection)
            {
                IDs += id.ToString() + ",";
            }
            try
            {
                string test = IDs.Substring
                              (0, IDs.LastIndexOf(","));
                string sql = "Delete from Registers" + " WHERE ID in (" + test + ")";
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandText = sql;
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                string errorMsg = "Error in Deletion";
                errorMsg += ex.Message;
                throw new Exception(errorMsg);
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }
        }
        protected void polyuria2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (CheckBox1.Checked == true)
            {
                var peradrs = txtAddressCon.Text;
                var stat = ddlStatePermanent.SelectedIndex;
                var contry = ddlCountryPermanent.SelectedIndex;
                txtAddressPer.Text = peradrs;
                ddlStateCommunication.SelectedIndex = stat;
                ddlCountryCommunication.SelectedIndex = contry;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your page_load like? Can you share that code...

Comment: please help me friends

Comment: @deostroll i added full cs code

Comment: Hi. Each time you call update you are binding the gridview again with data from database. I think this causes the state of the checkbox to get reset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the ViewState unable to maintain CheckBox state from GridView column. Easiest solution will be:

Add 'OnCheckedChanged' and 'OnDataBinding' event for checkbox column

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:CheckBox ID="radID" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="radID_CheckedChanged" OnDataBinding="radID_DataBinding" />
</ItemTemplate>
```

Next step will be implement these events:

```
protected void radID_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox)sender;
    if (checkbox.Checked)
    {
        ViewState[checkbox.UniqueID] = true;
    }
    else
    {
        ViewState.Remove(checkbox.UniqueID);
    }
}

protected void radID_DataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox)sender;
    checkbox.Checked = ViewState[checkbox.UniqueID] != null;
}
```

Please let me know, if this helps.

Comment: Working fine. thank you